# Widget won't work/install

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, homescreen

My widget won't install. I'm trying to install a home screen widget using android. I've put the widgetprovider in the manifest along with a configuration class. It just doesn't show up in the list of widgets and I hence can't install it! Console gives no errors.

The update widget receiver is there in the manifest. But the widget isn't even created so what's the point? The widget won't get created!

I've created the layout, created the widget information file and filled in the fields, registered it in the manifest, created the classes, it still won't work.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".WidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_PROVIDE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
    </receiver>
    <activity
      android:name=".WidgetConfig"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_CONFIG" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: First of all, don't try to install your application on the external storage (don't know if you are trying this or not). Apps containing widgets must be installed on the internal storage.

Comment: Secondly, sometimes you need to start your MainActivity of the same application for Android to realize that you also have a widget. Thirdly, please include your manifest in the question.

Comment: I just put the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your manifest. The intent filter should contain

`action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"`

 not:
`action android:name="android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_PROVIDE"`

If you have more than one widget provider, each one needs its own receiver containing this action. Here is an example for one widget provider:

```
<receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
         </intent-filter>
         <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@layout/widget_provider_2x1"/>
     </receiver>
```